# Node attach VS Code debugger launch json

Tags: node.js, stdin, vscode-debugger

I am calling node from an external application (4D) which is same as command line stdin ie

```
node.exe --inspect-brk sharp.js filepath
```

I have setup a launch.json as follows. Tried port and process options etc.

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "4D Inspect-brk Attach to Process",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "attach",
        "port": 9229,
        "processId": "${command:PickProcess}"
      }
]
```

}

However the launch file does not automatically launch vs code debug mode. I still have to do ctrl-shift-p then pick the process. Gets a bit laborious.

Can someone put me out of my misery with an example.
Paul